# error_log getting huge

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging

Recently updated PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 and my error_log is getting really huge growing up about 100MB/minute.

I can see that it contains all types of errors including E_NOTICE and E_STRICT.

What do I change in order to log only E_ERROR messages into the file?

Please help or the file log will eat all hdd space that left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which operating system you're using but in general you should be able to configure this in the php.ini file which could be /etc/php.ini for a CentOS/RHEL system. It's a self documented file so you should be able to figure out what to do.

Comment: Thanks Iain, I've actually figured out that in php.ini my error_reporting setting was "E_ALL" and E_NOTICE is included into E_ALL since php 5.4